# Remember breakpoints when debugging using ipython

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

I use ipython and `run -d foo.py` to debug my program. But every time I re-debug the program, I have to reset all the breakpoints. This is annoying when you have multiple breakpoints or multiple `py` files.

Is it possible to let ipython or pdb to remember the breakpoints and reused them in next debug session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write an initialisation file for pdb which lists all the break points you want to add to the program. It must be called `.pdbrc` and placed either in the working directory or your home directory. Break points can be specified by either line number or by function name.

eg.

**a.py**

```
import b

def doX():
    print("in x") # line 4
    b.doY()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doX()
```

**b.py**

```
def doY():
    print("in y") # line 2
```

**.pdbrc**

```
# the following are all equivalent -- placing a breakpoint on entry into doX
break 4
break a.py:4
break doX
break a.doX

# placing a breakpoint on entry into doY
break b.py:2
break b.doY
```

**Output**

```
In [8]: %run -d a.py
Breakpoint 1 at /home/user/Desktop/python-stuff/a.py:1
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
Breakpoint 2 at /home/user/Desktop/python-stuff/a.py:3
Breakpoint 3 at /home/user/Desktop/python-stuff/b.py:1
> /home/user/Desktop/python-stuff/a.py(1)<module>()
1---> 1 import b
      2 
2     3 def doX():

ipdb> c
> /home/user/Desktop/python-stuff/a.py(4)doX()
2     3 def doX():
----> 4         print("in x")
      5         b.doY()

ipdb> c
in x
> /home/user/Desktop/python-stuff/b.py(2)doY()
3     1 def doY():
----> 2         print("in y")
      3 

ipdb> c
in y
```

Comment: Thanks @Dunes ! Just want to emphasis that, if the `b.py` is not in current directory, but in another folder `./dir1/dir2/b.py`. In the `.pdbrc`, we need to set `bread dir1/dir2/b.doY`.

Comment: Just checked, and pdb also includes the `restart` command which restarts the program with the same breakpoints and options. That was probably the simpler answer.